# Blender Python and pass settings

Tags: python, denoise, cryptomatte

Try this:

1. Manually set checkbox "Denoising Data" on
2. Log shows `bpy.context.scene.denoising_store_passes = True`
3. Copypaste exactly that into console and hit enter
4. Throws `AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute
   'denoising_store_passes'`

Same with i.e. cryptomatte. Am i doing anything wrong or is this simply not supported yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python tooltips are currently a bit broken for property groups, which also affects the commands displayed in the Info area.

The correct command for setting this option for the current view layer is:

```
bpy.context.view_layer.cycles.denoising_store_passes = True
```

If you want to refer to the scene and view layer by name:

```
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].view_layers['View Layer'].cycles.denoising_store_passes = True
```

Whenever you see a Python tooltip with an ellipsis (`...`) the command in the Info area is inaccurate.

[image: Example tooltip]

The issue is known and reported in [T69803](https://developer.blender.org/T69803).

Comment: Thanks, Robert! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

**The type is shown.**

In addition to RJG's answer can always see the registered type `bpy.types.Foo` in this example `Foo` is 
 `CyclesRenderLayerSettings`. The scene `context.scene` is  `Scene` type (the context of the error message in question, whereas) `scene.cycles` is `CyclesRenderLayerSettings` type.

Searching the docs on type

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/search.html?q=cyclesrendersettings&check_keywords=yes&area=default

We see it hits both the `Scene` and `Object` types. Scene is the choice here and

https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.Scene.html?highlight=cyclesrendersettings#bpy.types.Scene.cycles

points us to `scene.cycles`.  A quick trip to the python console to confirm and Bob's your uncle.

Edit: on closer inspection needed to be the viewlayer settings, but more often than not it points one in the right direction.