# How to use bpy.context.scene.use_denoising in Blender 2.8?

Tags: python, rendering, denoise

This give an error: `AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'use_denoising'`

I know that in the previous version like Blender 2.79 the command to access `use_denoising` was:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.layers[0].cycles.use_denoising
```

How to access this in Blender 2.8x?

This question is very specific to `use_denoising`, so it has no precise answer except in this post (at the moment), I think it can be useful to many.

The answers are given by @ydvisual and @batFINGER has specified an important question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender Python and pass settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160824/blender-python-and-pass-settings)

Comment: There is a distinct difference between *command*, *property (class attribute)* and *parameter*.

Comment: @p2or You're absolutely right, I corrected the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
bpy.context.scene.view_layers[0].cycles.use_denoising = True
```

Comment: Or `context.view_layer.cycles.use_denoising`

Comment: @batFINGER Do you think using bpy.context.scene.view_layers [0] could get errors in particular situations?

Comment: The context view layer may be view_layers[0] or  view_layers[1].... for each vew_layer in scene.  In general we are interested in changing objects that have context.   If you wish to change for all viewlayers in the scene would then use `for vl in scene.view_layers:`  Could say it's never a good idea to use first object in a collection if you are not sure that's the one you wish to update.